# On the existence of a partition (or being well defined)

Tags: real-analysis

Consider an uncountable set, e.g. the interval $A = [0,1]$. If I associate each $x \in A$ with a partition $P_x$ over an interval $B = [1,2]$, is the common refinement of all these partitions $P = \cup_{x\in A} P_x$ necessarily well defined/exists?

Comment: It may be defined however if we take e.g. $P_x = \{1,1+x,2\}$ then $$\bigcup_{x\in[0,1]} P_x = \bigcup_{x\in[0,1]} \{1,1+x,2\} = [1,2], $$
in which case the "partition" is the whole interval, and is no longer a partition in the classic sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, uncountable union is well-defined. It is simply:

$x\in P \leftrightarrow \exists y\in A$ where $x \in P_y $

However, it may not be have certain properties that you wanted to preserve about the original set (for example, whether it is measurable).